# Frequency of obtaining and releasing JDBC connections from ConnectionPools?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am in the process of refactoring a legacy system which has originally been designed in the mid-1990s. Back those days, JDBC connection were a scarce resource, there were no reliable connection pool implementations and therefore a connection was held as long as possible. This lead to constructs as these:

```
class ClientHandler {
  Connection conn=DriverManager.createConnection(...);
  Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
  Statement stmt2=conn.createStatement();

  public ReplyType handleCommand(RequestType req) {
    if (req.requestType==RequestType.LOGIN)
      return new LoginManager(stmt,stmt2).login(req.requestData);
    ...
  }
}

class LoginManager {
  Statement stmt,stmt2;
  public LoginManager(Statement stmtx,Statement stmt2x) { stmt=stmtx; stmt2=stmt2x; }
  public login(RequestData data) {
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from users where name="+data.getName()+" and pw="+data.getPassword());
    if (!rs.next()) throw new IllegalStateException();
    if (rs.getInt(1)==0)
      throw new WhateverException("error.wrongpassword");
  }
}
```

This is only an example to show that database connections in this structure

- are opened early
- are kept open for long times
- are passed around to everyone who has to access the database

Now, being in the process of refactoring, I want to remove this mode of operation. Thinking of connection pooling and operation as stateless as possible, I could imagine to remove every passing around of database connections and simply obtaining a database connection (from the pool) just as I need them and throw them away (back into the pool) always within the same scope. The same code as above could be rewritten like this (Java 7 try-with-resource style):

```
class ClientHandler {

  public ReplyType handleCommand(RequestType req) {
    if (req.requestType==RequestType.LOGIN)
      return new LoginManager().login(req.requestData);
    ...
  }
}

class LoginManager {
  public login(RequestData data) {
    try (Connection conn=StaticConnectionPoolBridge.createConnection) {
      ResultSet rs=conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select count(*) from users where name="+data.getName()+" and pw="+data.getPassword());
      if (!rs.next()) throw new IllegalStateException();
      if (rs.getInt(1)==0)
        throw new WhateverException("error.wrongpassword");
    }
  }
}
```

**My question**: Is it sensible to refactor this way? I mean, connection pools are meant to make database connection creation a lightwight operation. But is it *so* lightwight that you can just get and throw away in such a very fine-grained way? Or should I try to restrict the number of obtain-release cycles with the connection pool to some not-too-large number, e.g. by moving around obtained Connections and Statements at least to some (utility) methods? Are there any rules of thumb for working with connection pools in such systems?

FWIW: The backbone of the whole system is Play 2.3 which uses the BoneCP connection pool internally. Of course, the system in question features some layers of abstraction in the database access code which I left out here to make the example code as simple as possible.

Comment: If it's working I wouldn't touch it. If it has a connection-related problem you should certainly introduce a connection pool.

Comment: We have the connection pool up and available through Play. We want to make the old stuff freely available in the Play-based parts of the system and therefore the refactoring is needed anyway. I'd like to have some opinions on the access granularity to the connection pool from people who have more experience in working with those pools.

Comment: is it apparent where the transactions are in the legacy code? or is autocommit on?

Comment: The legacy code was originally designed on MySQL 3.22 with MyISAM tables. So, yes, autocommit is on. :-) The whole thing is about Connection instances, not about the logical connection lifecycle within the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining and releasing connections from a connection pool is very lightweight because the only thing you're eventually doing is taking/putting that connection back in a queue. You wouldn't be talking to the DB at all in those operations.

Comment: That is not necessarily true, the pool might reset some state on returning it to the pool (eg rollback open transaction, closing currently open result sets) and on obtaining it from the pool (eg checking if the connection is still valid)

Comment: True, though those are mostly optional and in a managed connection environment these are best switched off eg if you know for sure the RS and TX will be committed/rolled back no point in checking inside the pool.

Comment: I understand the general idea of connection pools. Nevertheless, even "taking/putting in a queue" becomes a problem if it is done too often. Let's say this happens 200 times a second. Problem?

Comment: Sure, at some point you're going to have locks in place which will limit you though I'd argue your next request to the DB (i.e. actually doing something with it) will take far longer. I'm actually the author of the (now deprecated) BoneCP library and certainly in a production environment you should barely see the connection open/close show up in a profiler. If you are using something like Spring, use the LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy so that a connection is only really "opened" (= fetched from pool) when you do useful SQL work

Comment: Take a look at https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/. I use it in production for years and it's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally finished the aforementioned refactoring. I actually ripped out almost all Statement passing and replaced it with extensive try-with-resource. Our framework contains something similar to LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy and I added a lightweight layer which binds Connections to Threads so that if the same Thread opens multiple parallel Statements, all are derived from the same Connection.

Working this way actually *increased* the speed of the system under certain workloads, and lead to *no* problems regarding the Connection Pool Engine. So, I would say this refactoring was a success and a Connection Pool like BoneCP can handle literally hundreds of Connection openings and closings per second.